# pointer de-referencing balagurusamy

Tags: c, pointers

What is the trouble with pointer dereferencing when , not dereferencing a pointer when required. Code given below.
what is the error here, not able to understand.
Given in balagurusamy book of ansi c.

```
int *p,m=100 ;
p = &x ;
printf("%d",p) ;/*error*/
```

Comment: What's `x`? Please post the whole code.

Comment: `"%d"` is used to print an `int`, `p` is not an `int` but a pointer to `int`  thus you are using a wrong format specifier, if you want to show the value of where the pointer points to, you need to dereference: `printf("%d", *p);`, if you want to show the value of the pointer itself you need to switch to a proper format specifier: `printf("%p", (void *)p);`

Answer (score 2):

Fixing a few things in code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *p, m = 100, x = 10;
    p = &x; // In words, making 'p' to point to the address of 'x'
    printf("Address %p contains a value %d..", (void *)p,   *p);
    //              ^^                         ^^^^^^^^^    ^
    //              Using the correct          Typecasting  Dereferencing
    //              format specifier           the pointer  the pointer
    //              
    // Some code
    return 0;
}
```

Generated output:

```
Address 0x7ffdf396c128 contains a value 10..
```

You are ought to get different result if you try the same code as the addresses are very unlikely to be same.

Explanation:

- `x` was undefined in the snippet you provided
- When a pointer is used to point to a compatible data type, you can print the value by dereferencing the pointer.
- If you want to print the value of the pointer itself, you need to first cast it to `void` and then use a `%p` format specifier rather than using `%d`.
- [List of common format specifier in C programming](https://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c-programming.html)